# How can I add a 32-bit image to an icon for a Visual Studio 2017 WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

It appears that the built-in image editor will let you add/edit 24-bit images (where a color is selected to represent transparent), but it doesn't seem to be able to handle 32-bit png images, despite the fact that when you add a new icon to a project, the new icon file includes 32-bit png images e.g. 256 x 256 32 bit png, which are supported by the format.

How does one create such resources, given that Visual Studio doesn't appear to have the capability built in or enabled "out of the box"?

Answer (score 3):

You can create and edit 32 bit png and icons with IcoFX (I use the "portable" version).  Why Visual Studio doesn't include this level of icon editing is beyond me - in fact, I could never figure why this capability isn't included in a built-in Windows program (and I've been using Windows since 3.0).